# Prevent Indexing of Images from my website but hosted on S3 / Cloudinary

Tags: seo, search-engines, sitemap, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt

I understand that as a website/domain owner (eg: example.com), we can prevent images from our website from being indexed by Google (GoogleBot / GoogleBot-Image).

We could add a meta tag to the whole page (which blocks indexing of the entire page. Not what we want.):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
```

Or we could add into the robots.txt to just block images:

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/
```

However, the image that I'd like to block is an image that is hosted on S3 / Cloudinary. Unlike the examples given by Google, the path to the image does not belong to my domain (example.com), instead, it has an Cloudinary address path.

eg: I have a page `example.com/cute-cats`. Inside, it has an image of a cat that belongs to me, but is uploaded and hosted in Cloudinary (eg: https://res.cloudinary.com/xyz123/image/upload/xxxyyyzzz111222/cute-cat.jpg).

1. How do I remove such an image if it already has been indexed and shows up in search results? The image is currently used as a thumbnail on Google Images that links back to example.com/cute-cats.
2. How do I prevent these images from being indexed again in the future?

Comment: Simply upload robots.txt to `https://res.cloudinary.com` with its own rules for that sub domain.

Comment: Okay? have you [tested the robots.txt](https://technicalseo.com/seo-tools/robots-txt/)?